# Percentages: Department of Meteorology

Tags: percentages

[image]

$1.$ I worked out $23 percent$ of all disasters that took place in Europe ($313$)

$0.77$ x $313$ $=$ $241.01$

$2.$ I then worked out $18percent$ of European disasters that were storms ($241.01$)

$0.82$ x $241.01$ $=$ $196.882$

I'm not sure what to do from then...

Comment: Is it just asking about year 3?

Comment: Yes, year 3 only... any ideas?  @Quality

Comment: I posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In year 3 we have a total of 313 disasters, of which 23% took place in Europe. Ie,$(313)(0.23)= 72$ disasters in Europe.

Of the 72 disasters in Europe, 18% were storms, so, there were $(72)(0.18)= 13$ storms in Europe in year 3.

By the way, the multiplication does not give those exactly but within a few decimals, you would have to round because a disaster is not something you can have half of for example.

But 131 storms took place in total so that is $131-13=118$ storms took place in the rest of the world.